# Datetimepicker not retaining value

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a date time picker on my VB.NET form and I set the value of it from code here.

```
Dim startDate As Date = CType(selectedStartDate, Date)
                dtpExepStartDate.Value = startDate
```

In this case the string selectedStartDate ="7/28/2014" and for some reason when I set the value of the date time picker to that date object it doesn't stick.

It just ends up showing today's date instead of 7/28/2014

I am really stumped on this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) is there any limit for dates range in your dtp? 2) are you sure startDate is a valid date (debug/log it)?

Answer (score 0):

I knew as soon as I posted a question here I would figure it out haha. Turns out there was another function that ran after I set the value that reset the value to today's date. Thanks anyways.